# Is there a best / OSX-specific way to force all files created in a directory to have certain group ownership?

Tags: permission, filesystem, unix, defaults, group

Basically I need any file *filefoo* that is newly created by *userfoo* or *userbar*, both members of *groupfoo*, in /Users/Shared/SpecialDirectory to have the same ownership that would be achieved by that user doing `chown whicheverusermadethefile:groupfoo filefoo` after the fact.

(Longer story: I have two users running simultaneously on the same machine. The users have a shared folder at /Users/Shared/SpecialDirectory. These users, say *userfoo* and *userbar*, are both already members of a group *groupfoo*. *userfoo* syncs this directory using Dropbox, but Dropbox can't sync files downloaded by *userbar* into that directory b/c of permissions. File-by-file or a bunch at a time this problem can be solved with `chown` and adding the right group ownership to the file or directory, but new downloads or additions continue to pose a problem. Thanks to some old tinkering with `umask` the files are created with the correct group permissions such that *userfoo*'s Dropbox instance can read and sync them when their ownership is *anyuser:groupfoo*, but the group itself is wrong because new file ownership defaults to *userbar:staff* instead of *userbar:groupfoo*.)

PS: [This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/77007/how-can-i-make-a-folder-and-its-contents-automatically-owned-by-two-people?rq=1) is closest to the one I'm asking about, but the suggested solutions don't seem to apply since they don't ensure correct ownership of new files. Also, I could be wrong, but it looks like the questions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44534/how-to-set-umask-for-a-specific-folder), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580584/setting-default-permissions-for-newly-created-files-and-sub-directories-under-a), and [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3670301?start=0&tstart=0) aren't what I need, because the permissions are correct--it's the ownership that's wrong--and I need the fix to apply to any process creating any file (in particular b/c the bulk of these files-to-be-shared are pdfs downloaded by Chrome). [This](https://superuser.com/questions/437781/how-do-i-set-default-group-ownership-for-files-in-a-directory) one also doesn't seem to do it--the directory itself is already owned by *userfoo:groupfoo*, yet new files created by *userbar* don't get the *groupfoo* gid.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question but does `chgrp groupfoo thedirectory; chmod g+s thedirectory` not have the desired effect? This sounds like the standard scenario for directories with the setgid bit set. I don't think you need ACLs for this.

Comment: I think you're right and I'm an idiot and didn't check carefully enough what I had done. I need to wait a bit to ensure that this is right and then I'm going to flag my q or something b/c it would then be a clear dupe of the last link I cite.

Comment: OK so I realized the issue--I download file `bar` in `~/downloads` and move to `/users/shared/specialdirectory` but `bar` doesn't then "inherit" the group newly created files in `specialdirectory` do. So this is not the question I asked, but it is the issue I meant to address. Any thoughts?